# Grouping child processes with setpgid()

Tags: c, linux, process

I just don't get the whole thing.

My process tree:

```
     0
    / \
   1   2
  /     \
 5       3
        / 
       4
```

I want to make a process group (3, 4, 5), and send this group a signal from, say, 2.

I tried it this way:

```
setpgid(pid3, pid3);
setpgid(pid4, pid3);
setpgid(pid5, pid3);

...

kill(-pid3, SIGUSR1);
```

Where should I place my `setpgid()` block? I tried placing it in 3, 0 and every other process, but `setpgid()`s return either "No such process" or "Operation not permitted".

pids are stored in files, so I retrieve them just before calling `setpgid()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A process can set the process group ID of **only itself or any of its children**. Furthermore, it can't change the process group ID of one of its children after that child has called one of the exec functions.   --APUE

In my opinion,

1.a grandparent can't use setgpid() with its gradechild, you can check this easily.That's to say, the code in pid 0 below won't work:

> ```
> setpgid(pid3, pid3); 
> setpgid(pid4, pid3);
> setpgid(pid5, pid3);
> ```

2.you can only use setgpid() to change one's and itselves chilld pgid,you can't write down setpgid(pid5, pid3) in pid 3, because pid 3 and pid 5 aren't parent and child.

So, you'd better use setgpid(someone's pid, pgid) in itself.

But how can one process know other processes' pid? A method is shared memory.

Here is one rough but a litte complex implement I just wrote, which don't consider process synchronization.It works as you expected.

```
#include "stdlib.h" 
#include "stdio.h"
#include "errno.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "sys/stat.h"
#include "sys/types.h"
#include "sys/ipc.h"
#include "sys/shm.h"
#include "signal.h"
#define PERM S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR

void sig_usr3(int);
void sig_usr4(int);
void sig_usr5(int);

int main() {
    size_t msize;
    key_t shmid;
    pid_t *pid;
    msize = 6 * sizeof(pid_t);
    if( (shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, msize , PERM)) == -1 )   { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Share Memory Error:%s\n\a", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    pid = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
    memset(pid,0,msize);
    pid[0] =  getpid();
    //process 0
    if(fork() == 0) {
    //process 1 
        pid = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        pid[1] =  getpid();
        if(fork() == 0) {
            //process 5
            pid = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
            pid[5] =  getpid();
            while(pid[3]==0)
                sleep(1);
            if((setpgid(pid[5],pid[3]))==-1)
                printf("pid5 setpgid error.\n");
            signal(SIGUSR1,sig_usr5);
            for(;;) 
                pause();
        }
        for(;;) 
            pause();
        exit(0);
      }

    if(fork() == 0) {
        //process 2
        pid = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        pid[2] =  getpid();
        if(fork() == 0) {
            //process 3
            pid = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
            pid[3] =  getpid();
            if((setpgid(pid[3],pid[3]))==-1)
                printf("pid3 setpgid error.\n");
            if(fork() == 0) {
                //process 4
                pid = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
                pid[4] =  getpid();
                if((setpgid(pid[4],pid[3]))==-1)
                    printf("pid4 setpgid error.\n");
                signal(SIGUSR1,sig_usr4);
                for(;;)
                    pause();
            }
            else {
                signal(SIGUSR1,sig_usr3);
                for(;;)  
                    pause();
            }
            for(;;)  
                sleep(100); 
    }

    if(getpid()==pid[0]) {
        int i,flag;
        while(!(pid[0]&&pid[1]&&pid[2]&&pid[3]&&pid[4]&&pid[5]))
            //wait for all process folking.
            sleep(1);

        for(i=0;i<6;i++)
            printf("process %d,pid:%d\n",i,pid[i]);
        kill(-pid[3],SIGUSR1);
    }
}

void sig_usr3(int signo) {
    if(signo == SIGUSR1)
        printf("recieved sigal in process 3\npid is %d\n\n",getpid());
    exit(0);
}

void sig_usr4(int signo) {
    if(signo == SIGUSR1)
        printf("recieved sigal in process 4\npid is %d\n\n",getpid());
    exit(0);
}

void sig_usr5(int signo) {
    if(signo == SIGUSR1)
        printf("recieved sigal in process 5\npid is %d\n\n",getpid());
    exit(0);
}
```

output:

```
process 0,pid:31361
process 1,pid:31362
process 2,pid:31363
process 3,pid:31364
process 4,pid:31366
process 5,pid:31365
recieved sigal in process 3
pid is 31364

recieved sigal in process 5
pid is 31365

recieved sigal in process 4
pid is 31366
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice example. Things got a lot easier when I realised that I don't need any process synchronizaton, nor shared memory tricks. I created a group (2, 3, 4) with `setpgid(getpid(), getpgid(getppid()))` in 3 and 4. That was just what I needed. Obviously, for more complex task I'd consider your solution.