# Kill all child processes that used exec, c++

Tags: c++, pid

I don't know if this is the best way but I have a random number of child processes who have beed execed and wanted to implement a way to kill them without using ctrl+c. I was thinking of keeping a set of their pids and then check that set whenever I want to kill them from the parent process.

The way I was trying to do it was something like this

```
set<pid_t> pids;
pid_t id = fork();
if(id == 0)
{
    pids.insert(getpid());
    execlp("./somewhere", "./somewhere", something.c_str(), NULL);
    cout << "Didn't exec" << endl;
    exit(0);
}

for(auto i : pids)
{
    kill(i, something?)
}
```

I still don't quite know how to use the kill function or how pids work so I don't know if this will work in any way, I just did a simple project in c for college and though I could try something more complex in c++.
Anyways, the objective of this is to be able to have the parent process kill a single child process out of an undefined number of running child processes, or kill them all whenever the user writes quit

Comment: The code you show is C++.  Don't tag C++ code with C.  Choose a single language tag — either C or C++, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kill()` on pid 0 sends the signal to all members of the calling process group:

> If pid is 0, sig shall be sent to all processes (excluding an
> unspecified set of system processes) whose process group ID is equal
> to the process group ID of the sender, and for which the process has
> permission to send a signal.

If you want to `kill` only certain processes (as seems to be your case) take a look to [Grouping child processes with setpgid()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639275/grouping-child-processes-with-setpgid)